# usage of standard backward relation manager in serilizers

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Question is about using standard Django backward related manager name in DRF.

I have following serializer

```py
class ExtraUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    boatmodel_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,
                                            queryset=BoatModel.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("id", "username", 'boatmodel_set', )
```

This serializer represents primary model ExtraUser and boat_model set represents backward relationship to secondary model  BoatModel. Related name “boatmodel_set” chosen simply because main core Django site uses this standard “secondarymodel_set” conventional backward related manager name so that in DRF part  I had to use related_name = “ boatmodel_set” as well in order to not change code in the main part.

Question is  - is it possible to keep related_name = “ boatmodel_set”  but represent it in rendered json as , for example “boats”??
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can just specify the [**`source=`** parameter [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source), and name the field differently, like:

```
class ExtraUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    boats = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=BoatModel.objects.all(),
        source='boatmodel_set'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'boats')
```

Here the JSON-side will contain `"boats": ...`, whereas the model side will still use `myuser.boatmodel_set.all()`.